# Why my Java code is working in windows and not on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, frames

Here is my code. I'm a beginner learning core Java. I program on MacBook Air 2017. While performing a "Frame" program, the code is perfect and it runs without any errors. Like I have to change background of window gradually after a second. When I run it on windows, it works perfectly fine. But when I run on Mac, it doesn't change any background colour but starts changing colour of title bar. Is there any settings I need to change?

```
import java.awt.*;
class abc extends  Frame
{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
       
        int red,green,blue;
        red = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        green = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        Color c1 = new Color(red,green,blue);
        setBackground(c1);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ae)
        {}
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc obj1 = new abc();
        obj1.setVisible(true);
        obj1.setSize(500,500);

    }

}
```

[I have added this Youtube link. Please check What Output I'm getting.](https://youtu.be/1Cun22QQyhU)

Comment: Do u have Java Installed on your Mac ?

Comment: Yes. Obviously. Please check the below Youtube link, that's my output.

Comment: No one will be watching a youtube video: [put all the details in your post first](/help/how-to-ask), with links to _support_ that information only. People should be able to help you based on your post and _only_ your post.

Comment: UI is hard, don't try to make it simple. Your repaint must happen on the EDT thread, and it's clearly not doing that. Or if you do, you sleep it. Either way, check what EDT is and study it and then only create a test project based on that. Never ever sleep on the EDT and especially in the `paint` method.

Comment: When overriding paint(), you should call the superclass' paint() method. ``super(g);`` as your first line.

Comment: You should not swallow any exceptions. At the very least, you should call ``ae.printStackExchange();``

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the window is not repainted (color changes when you resize the window, which, among other things, triggers a repaint event). That's perfectly valid behaviour, it just happens that Windows does that by itself and Mac OS X doesn't.

<s>I didn't use Swing outside of some college assignmenets (I used other UI frameworks), but looking at Javadocs I would try one of these methods after setting a new background color:</s>

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate()

Edit: I noticed it's `paint` method. I don't know what exactly happens, but `paint` should be called just once. Probably `sleep` cause the program to repaint and may cause the weird behaviour seen in the clip. Move this code to a separate thread.

```
public class ColorRotator extends Thread {

  final private Frame frame;
  public boolean active = true;

  public ColorRotator (Frame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (active) {
        int red,green,blue;
        red = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        green = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        blue = (int) (Math.random()*255);
        Color c1 = new Color(red,green,blue);
        frame.setBackground(c1);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```